# Negative Jacobian Values

Tags: linear-algebra, jacobian

Can you have a negative Jacobian? And if so, what effect does it have on area, volume, etc.?

I know the determinant of the Jacobian is in absolute value.

Comment: Let $T(x,y) = (x,-y)$.  The determinant of the partial derivatives matrix is $-1$.  What effect does $T$ have on area?

Comment: More relevantly to your question, what effect does that $T$ have on orientation?